# Test for multiple conditions in same if test?

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators

I tried googling and failed.

Using C, I have an IF statement. I want to test a variable against two non-consecutive values.

Is it possible to do

> if (state == 1 || 3)

Meaning if state is 1 or if state is 3.

Or does it have to be

> if (state == 1 || state == 3)

I'm thinking the first actually means if state is 1, or 3, which means the test will always be true (if true or true).

### Is there a way to write this without having to rewrite the variable name multiple times?

No, I don't want to use a `case` / `switch` statement. I'm trying to type less.

Comment: Have you had a look at the formal grammar defined in the C-standard? Specifically C11 draft standard n1570, `6.5 Expressions`?

Comment: To save typing you could perhaps use a macro, `#define TEST2(var, a, b) ( (var) == (a) || (var) == (b) )`. (bear in mind that this evaluates `var` twice still). You could write an inline function to avoid the double evaluation. If you have many cases then use a `switch`.

Comment: @M.M The best part of that macro is that you can even do `TEST2(a++, 1, 3)` **and the behavior is well defined**. That's a wonderful thing, and kind of rare for macros.

Comment: @EOF I just tried. My eyes glazed over trying to read it. But I didn't see anything that would address this.

Comment: @cde: Well, there's `6.5 Expressions, 3 The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax. 85) The syntax specifies the precedence of operators in the evaluation of an expression, which is the same as the order of the major subclauses of this subclause, highest precedence first.[...]`, so you know that `==` has higher precedence than `||`.

Comment: @EOF well-defined, yes but probably not what was intended!

Comment: Yes, there are ways: `if (abs(state - 2) == 1)` works, using `state` only once.  Certainly `if (state == 1 || state == 3)` is easier to understand.

Comment: If the states are no greater than 127 you could write `if ( strchr("\x01\x03", state) )`

Comment: @M.M  That passes 1,3 and 0.

Comment: @chux true, so it would have to come after `if (state == 0)` in the if..else sequence :D  Or use `memchr`.

Comment: @M.M  like `if(memchr("\x01" "\x03", state, 2)) ...`?

Comment: Yeah, I would not bother with separate string literals tho

Comment: @cde Aside from 1 or 3, what values might `state` have? 0, -1, 1000000, 1.23?

Comment: @chux currently, 0, 2, 4. I have rearranged the states to make the test easier (if state <= 1), but I was asking for general reference. I may not always be able to arrange the variable in a consecutive manner. I was hoping there was something simpler than multiple conditionals or switch/case statement.

Comment: It probably took you more time to ask the question (by *typing*) than it will  save you all year in typing code!

Comment: @cde  With 0 can use M.M idea `if(strchr("\2\4", state))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use the long variant

```
if (state == 1 || 3)
```

evaluates always to `true` because it is interpreted as

```
if ((state == 1) || (3))
```

EDIT:

Because for C++ was asked in the comments an M.M mentioned operator overloading, a C++ solution

```
#include <cstdlib>
struct State {
    struct Proxy {
        int v;
        bool res;
        Proxy(int v, bool res) : v(v), res(res) {}

        Proxy operator || (int a) const {
            return Proxy(v, res || (a == v));
        }

        operator bool() const { return res; }
    };
    int v;
    State(int v) : v(v) {}

    Proxy operator == (int a) {
        return Proxy(v, a == v);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    State   state(atoi(argv[1]));

    if (state == 1 || 3 || 5)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking. So there's no short form option at all?

Comment: nothing, which would be shorter than `(state == 1) || (state == 3)`.  Depending on your use case you can define macros to avoid writing redundant code.  Our -- when `state` is small-- you can define a table to speedup check when many cases must be checked.

Comment: Does c++ address this?

Comment: no; neither C nor C++ have a native `is in` operator.

Comment: obviously you could write an `if ( is_in(state, 1, 3) )` in both languages

Comment: @M.M is that a standard function? I can't find it in IAR Workbench or a google search.

Comment: Wow, that c++ solution is a bit beyond me. Thanks for the work though. I'll accept in a day or two if no one else answers :)

Comment: @cde no, I'm saying you could write a function with that name

Answer (score 1):

@cde, 'C' programming doesn't have a construct to use the expression like in the first form, so you have to use the second form, as many have already mentioned above.

You might try the following approach, if the values are known ahead of comparison, either by including them at the time of declaration or populate with the values at a later time (which might of fixed or variable set, in which case the array has to be allocated dynamically and size must have already been available by then).

Note: inline, static, const aren't really necessary for the solution to work.  Also, it has the advantage that the function returns as soon as the condition evaluates to true skips the rest of the comparisons, unless the state doesn't match with any of the given states.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


inline bool isInKnownStates(int state, const int ds[], const int sz)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (; (i < sz) && (state != ds[i]); i++);

    return (i < sz);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    static const int discrete_states[] = {1, 3};
    static const int sz = sizeof(discrete_states)/sizeof(discrete_states[0]);
    int state0 = 0;
    int state1 = 1;
    int state3 = 3;

    cout << state0 << " " << (isInKnownStates(state0, discrete_states, sz) ? "True" : "False") << endl << flush;
    cout << state1 << " " << (isInKnownStates(state1, discrete_states, sz) ? "True" : "False") << endl << flush;
    cout << state3 << " " << (isInKnownStates(state3, discrete_states, sz) ? "True" : "False") << endl << flush;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure. It might not be as simple as multiple individual expressions as in second firm, and not having to write it multiple times make it easier to use.  Also lends it to the form that @sun-qingyao mentioned below. For example,  `cout << state0x1000 << " " << (isInKnownStates(state0x1000, (int[]){1, 3, 256, 0x1000}, 4) ? "True" : "False") << endl << flush;` works correctly. The `memchr` only for integer values that can be specified using 'char' type as the function expects and treats the values as chars rather than int.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to write this without having to rewrite the variable
>   name multiple times?

Well, yes. `#include <string.h>` and you can use

```
if(memchr(&(char []){1, 3}, state, 2))
```

0r

```
if(memchr(&(char []){1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, state, 5))
```

Note that `state` mustn't contain values beyond the scope of `char`(signedness can be specified as need), or information might be lost. You cannot use an array of type T when `sizeof (T) != 1`. The reduce of  readability will also be taken into consideration.

Comment: This will also evaluate as true for `state == 0`. I'd say it's a bad idea to call `memchr()` on an `int`-array.